# Using statement doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, .net, exception, using, using-statement

My class named S looks like that:

```
public class S : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // some code
    }

    public void f()
    {
        throw new Exception("exception");
    }
}
```

When I use using statement, f() method doesn't call s.Dispose() method. I thought it should call Dispose method even if the exception occurs. That's what I read in MSDN: "The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object". Am I missing something?

```
using (S s = new S())
{
    s.f();
}
```

Calling s.f() ends my program without disposing of my object s. I think I don't have to use try/catch, because using statement should do it for me.

Comment: It works for me. If you put a `Console.WriteLine("Disposed");` inside `Dispose`, it does indeed write that to the console before propagating the exception out of the `using` block.

Comment: What's "some code"? How are you sure it doesn't call dispose?

Comment: @DavidS. you can be pretty sure if you try this code in a console application

Comment: @David S. as "simple code" I tried: 
`System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\exception.txt", System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew);
fs.Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("object disposed"), 0, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("object disposed").Length); 
fs.Close();`

Comment: Normally it's creating a file. Not in C:\, but in VirtualStore folder, so I know that my "some code" works. But `Dispose` is not called when calling `s.f()`.

Comment: I think this question could be useful for someone who has got the same problem. I mean someone who reads a book or documentation and tries to do all example code to see effects. He/she may not know that it should be run without debugger to work correctly. You shouldn't close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be that you are running the code in the debugger. That means that whatever code comes after an unhandled exception wont be executed becuase the debugger will halt at that point.

If you run a test scenario out of the debugger then the `Dispose()` method will be called when the runtime cleans up the mess. Put some code "marker" in the Dispose() method that will give you a visible sign  that Dipose is called: for example create a file in some accessible folder namesd *DisposedHasRun.yeah* (note that outputting to the Console or a `MessageBox` is not an option because the application is quitting due to an unhandled exception). When you run the test case outside the debugger you'll see that the file has been created.

That said, there are ocassions where `Dispose` wont be called (nor `finally` blocks). For example an `StackOverflow` exception due to an infinite recursion will not call `Dispose()` as the runtime will make the application bail out asap. (`ThreadAbortException` I think will behave the same)

Comment: Care explaining the downvotes?

Comment: I didn't vote, the gist of your answer seems right, but your very first sentence seems like it's making an unwarranted assumption.

Comment: I tried this in both Debug and Release modes and it's certainly terminating the program and doesn't call the Dispose

Comment: I run it without debugger too and it behaves in the same way.

Comment: @Selman22 Release or Debug build doesnt really matter. Its running the build (F5) from VS that matters. Just execute the .exe file from windows explorer if possible.

Comment: that didn't change the result

Comment: @Selman22 Of course not, if you are expecting to see "Disposed" in the Console. The application has essentially terminated so you can't output anything through it's UI.

Comment: Sorry @InBetween, you're right. It's not creating new file in Dispose method ( I don't know why), but showing MessageBox when running without debugger :) When debugging - it doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

> Am I missing something?

A `using` statement is converted into a `try ... finally` statement.

According to the [`try ... finally` C# reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx),

> Within a handled exception, the associated **finally** block is guaranteed to be run. However, if the exception is unhandled, execution of the **finally** block is dependent on how the exception unwind operation is triggered. That, in turn, is dependent on how your computer is set up.

So yes, you are missing something: that a `finally` block (and thus a call to `Dispose` in a `using` statement) is *not* guaranteed to fire in all circumstances, including in your circumstance, that of an unhandled exception.

The page goes on to advise:

> Usually, when an unhandled exception ends an application, whether or not the **finally** block is run is not important. However, if you have statements in a **finally** block that must be run even in that situation, one solution is to add a **catch** block to the **try-finally** statement. Alternatively, you can catch the exception that might be thrown in the **try** block of a **try-finally** statement higher up the call stack. That is, you can catch the exception in the method that calls the method that contains the **try-finally** statement, or in the method that calls that method, or in any method in the call stack. If the exception is not caught, execution of the **finally** block depends on whether the operating system chooses to trigger an exception unwind operation.

I'd be happier if I could find references in the C# specification. Unfortunately my reading of §8.9.5 is that even an unhandled exception should cause all `finally` statements on the way up the stack to execute.

Comment: It makes sense, because when I'm using `try/finally` block instead of `using statement`, it doesn't execute `finally` as well.

Comment: Sorry, it's calling `Dispose` and `finally` code when running without debugger.

Comment: @BlackCamel "not guaranteed to fire" is not the same as "guaranteed not to fire"

Answer (score -1):

in your comment your saying your using this code in your dispose

```
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\exception.txt",
                                                   System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew);
fs.Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("object disposed"), 0, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("object disposed").Length); 
fs.Close();
```

if you read how [FileStream FileMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) work;

> CreateNew
>
> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. This
>   requires FileIOPermissionAccess.Write permission. If the file already
>   exists, an IOException exception is thrown.

I'm pretty sure your dispose throw an exception since the file already exist.

check if the file exist then use `System.IO.FileMode.Append` if needed

Comment: It doesn't exist, because when it exists - I delete it. P.S. I'm not downvoting.